# Accidental re-vote locks it permanently

Tags: bug, up-votes

I up-voted a question. My up-vote got marked. I also up-voted one of the comments on the question. Then I accidentally closed the window. Using Google Chrome's Ctrl+Shift+T, I reopened the closed window. I noticed that my votes were missing. I up-voted the question again. It got marked. It said "You voted on this question 6 minutes ago. Your vote is locked until the question is edited." I knew something was wrong.

I reloaded the page. The up-votes on both the question and the comment were visible. However, my up-vote on the question was locked.

**I assume this is a bug.** If not, please let me know.

Comment: Votes are locked in after 5 minutes, it had nothing to do with your double upvoting

Comment: To clarify @Kevin's comment, when you re-opened the closed window, it evidently used a cached copy of the page, from before you had upvoted.  The vote was still registered, but wasn't being displayed to you.  If you had refreshed the page, you would have seen your upvote already there.  When you clicked the upvote button the second time, it assumed you were trying to remove your upvote, because the server had already registered the upvote (even though it wasn't being displayed to you).  It informed you that you can't change your vote, because too much time had elapsed.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Isn't that a bug? Shouldn't the page automatically require a reload of the page, if you are accessing a cached copy and would like to vote?

Comment: I'm no expert in web technology, but I don't know if that's always possible. It's probably at the very least extremely cumbersome to have all your code constantly checking this kind of thing. And I think that until the user does something to activate some code (e.g. Click the upvote button), there may be no way to actually have code run. But again, I'm no expert in web technology. It seems to me, though that this is no different than hundreds of other websites that might display out-of-date info until the page is refreshed.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I'm no expert either, but it must be possible. For example, if you log in to GMail, then disconnect from the net some time later (even if you are on another tab), you get notified that you are disconnected.